# (Dis)continuity of stepfunction in topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to learn a little about topology, and I don't quite understand continuity yet. I use this definition of a continuous map f:  f is continuous if the inverse image of every open set is open.

I use the sets $\mathbb{R}$ and $A = \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, both with standard metric topology (can I do that with $A$? I don't see something going wrong).

Now I look at the map f: $ A \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }x<0 \\
1 & \text{if }x>0
\end{cases}
$$

Now I ask myself whether this is continuous, so I look at the inverse image $B \subseteq A$ of any open set $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and I notice:

$$
B =
\begin{cases}
\emptyset & \text{if } 0 \notin C \wedge 1 \notin C \\
(0,+\infty) & \text{if } 0 \notin C \wedge 1 \in C \\
(-\infty,0) & \text{if } 0 \in C \wedge 1 \notin C \\
\mathbb{R} & \text{if } 0 \in C \wedge 1 \in C \\
\end{cases}
$$

These sets all seem open to me, which would imply that f is contiuous. But it can't be. What am I missing?

Comment: Your map is actually continuous. Maybe you are confused by the fact that f changes value as you cross $0$. But the point is that $0$ doesn't belong to the domain of f, so this is not a problem.

Comment: Oh. That's unexpected. But thanks!

Comment: The domain is not connected because of the 'missing' point at 0. The function $f$ is constant on each connected component, hence continuous. Intuitively, we 'assume' connectivity (at least I do!).

Comment: If you haven't already, you'll probably come across the notion of "connectedness". What you can see happening here is that $A$ consists of two different disjoint "connected" components, $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$. It turns out, which is what you've seen a case of, that a function is continuous if and only if it is so on each of its connected components (as it is in this case). Edit: Okay, that's what copper.hat said as well.

Comment: The "non continuous appearance" of f comes from the fact that it admits no continuous extension defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: In general, you can only apply the intuitive 'don't take the pencil off the paper' definition of continuity if the domain and range are path-connected subsets of the real line. The domain in your example fails the path-connected condition.

Comment: Thank you all! It's clear now